# how to Run Blender python code in Pycharm python file?

Tags: python, blender

want to run python functions which i have written in Blender through Pycharm python file on conditionals statements, how would i do that?

i want to run these blender's python functions inside the Pycharm python file on specific conditions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.